# Does Spring make sure Closeable beans are closed in the correct order?

Tags: java, spring

Let's pretend that we have two `Closeable` beans:

```
@Component
public class CloseableBean1 implements Closeable {

    private BufferedOutputStream outputStream;

    @Override
    public void close() throws IOException {
        try {
            outputStream.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // ignore e
        }
    }
}


@Component
public class CloseableBean2 implements Closeable {    

    @Autowired
    private CloseableBean1 bean1;


    @Override
    public void close() throws IOException {
        try {
            bean1.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // ignore e
        }
    }
}
```

Does Spring make sure that `CloseableBean2` is closed first and then `CloseableBean1` is closed?

Comment: Why is there an order to respect? Closing twice should not raise an exception as per the contract of [`close`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/Closeable.html): *If the stream is already closed then invoking this method has no effect.*

Comment: Let's pretend you have a bean (e.g. `Bean1`) that has a member of type `BufferedOutputStream` and another bean that depends on it (e.g. `Bean2`). If `Bean1`'s `BufferedOutputStream` is closed while the other bean is assuming that it is open and is trying to write to it, things can go wrong (exceptions thrown, etc.).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is nothing specific in documentation about order of disposing, but... 
the [description](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-factory-dependson) of `depends-on` we can see, that `depends-on` should be used only if bean does not explicitly depend on another. And there is noted, that dependent bean will always be destroyed first.

In your case bean `CloseableBean2` *always* will be destroyed first, because it contains explicitly dependency of `CloseableBean`.

---

I would prefer to make additional protection. Something like:

```
@Component
public class CloseableBean1 implements Closeable {

    private boolean closed = false;

    @Override
    public void close() throws IOException {
        if(closed) return;   
        outputStream.close();
        closed=true;
    }
}
```

Official documentation [recommend](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/Closeable.html#close--) us:

> ...and to internally mark the Closeable as closed, prior to throwing the IOException.

This approach helps to avoid accidental repeated call of `close()` on already closed stream. But if exception will occurred during first invocation of `close()`, we will able to handle it.

Comment: That seemed to be the way it works to me as well. I ran my smallish app multiple times and every time the order of `close` calls was the same: the _parent_ beans were getting closed first and then their respective _child_ beans. Could you please elaborate about that extra level of protection? Also you have not set `closed` to `true` in the `close()` method.

Comment: "In your case bean CloseableBean2 always will be destroyed first, because it contains explicitly dependency of CloseableBean." -> Is this correct? I think that calling `close()` on `CloseableBean2` is what happens first, but the bean itself cannot be considered as closed without closing its dependencies. Thus, each `close()` is calling its dependent bean `close()`method. So you call `close()` on `CloseableBean2`, but `BufferedOutputStream` in `CloseableBean1` gets closed first, then `CloseableBean1` and finally `CloseableBean2`.